# jquery ui dialog (with input) dont destroy

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

There is a text area within the dialog and it has an id.
If I want to get the content of the text area it shows every time the first given value. So if I close and reopen it, it does not recognize the changes. This problem should be solved.

[example-jsbin](http://jsbin.com/opaqok)

I think maybe the closed dialog's are not well destroyed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead:

```
dialog('close');
```

make this:

```
dialog().remove();
```