# Iframe in the jquery UI dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an iframe in the jquery UI dialog , setting its src at doument.ready event :

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#iframe").attr("src", whatever);
     $("#button").click(function() { $("#dialog").dialog(); });
    });

    <div id="dialog">
     <iframe src="" id="iframe"></iframe>
    <div>
```

Everything is going fine, when i `click over the button dialog open` but `the problem` is that it `loads iframe content everytime when dialog open`.I `want to stop` this behaviour and `load the contents only once at document.ready event`.How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use another iframe, hidden, then on dialog open just copy its content to your iframe in the dialog.

Comment: how we can copy the contents?

Comment: `var content = $('#hidden-iframe').html(); $('#iframe').html(content);`

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that JqueryUI destroys the dialog when you close it.

Here's a simple workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9128123/477176